# scrapy:how to skip the urls which don't response?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

scrapy crawl some pages, but every time the crawler stopped when it crawl the one of them ,and i find the reason is:there are some urls don't response,open the urls with browser,there is noting ,is blank,not 404.and this cause the crawler stopped. what should I do? English is not my mother language，I am not sure I describe it clearly.

add some description:
the crawler is writed by scrapy+redis+mongodb.and there are about 70 list-page,every list-page has 10 urls to detail-page,so,correct total pages are about 70*10=700,but when the pages are about 400, crawler can't get any more pages,the infomation is:

```
2015-10-14 22:28:13 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 1192 pages (at 76 pages/min), scraped 443 items (at 35 items/min)
2015-10-14 22:29:13 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 1192 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 443 items (at 0 items/min)
```

"Crawled 1192 pages":there are some ajax requests and list-page requests,so the pages is more than 700.
and i find the reason causing the crawler stopped is that there are some urls don't response.open the urls with browser,there is noting ,is blank,not 404.and,these pages that no response ,i want to ignore them,continue to crawl next page.

@Shekhar Samanta said:
"use :-

```
try:
    your line to make http requests
except:
    pass
```

with the help of this your crawler will not break ."
so, this is the code about http requests of this crawler,i don't know how to add "try except" to my code:

```
def parse(self,response):
    url_list = response.xpath('//div[@class="title"]/a/@href')
    for url in url_list:
        fullurl=response.urljoin(url.extract())
        yield Request(fullurl, callback=self.parseContent)

def parseContent(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="content"]'):
        item = ArticlespiderItem()
        item['articleUrl']=response.url
        item['aticleTitle']=sel.xpath('div[1]/div[1]/h3/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

Comment: Without some code and log information how do you expect us to give you a working answer?

Comment: this is just the parse function . Is there any problem with this ?

Comment: add .extract() at end of line - url_list = response.xpath('//div[@class="title"]/a/@href').extract()

Comment: fullurl=response.urljoin(url.extract())，fullurl is the url that the crawler will request ,so:'try:
    your line to make http requests
except:
    pass'where should i use this?

Comment: If you're getting to a blank page, with nothing to parse from it, and there are no more links in queue, you won't crawl anything else (as there's nothing left to crawl).  Without more information (such as the log), there's not much more people can help you with.

Comment: I have added some descripition,and,there is no other error infomation.

Comment: *"there are some ajax requests and list-page requests"*: Scrapy will not process Javascript, so it's actually generating the near 1200 requests.  They may be redirects, though.  Next, is the crawling stopping, as in, it finished it's job?  Or is it hanging/freezing?  By default, Scrapy will still pass the response object (it has way more than just response.body) through all middlewares and to the appropriate callback function, even when the body is empty.  If that callback function doesn't do anything with it, it will just move on to the next queued request.

Comment: 1、ajax requests urls are jionted by re,Scrapy didn't process Javascript ，and,ajax requests work correctly.2、700 detail pages are 700 items ,that's the all job,when it finished 443 items,then,it stopped,and the infomation appear.--Crawled 1192 pages (at 76 pages/min), scraped 443 items (at 35 items/min)--

Comment: may be I should confirm whether 700-443=257pages don't response,if so,the problem is resolved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scrapy crawler can't get all the pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129332/scrapy-crawler-cant-get-all-the-pages)

Comment: Unless you've enabled the "AjaxCrawlMiddleware" (and the site is compatible with it), then no, Scrapy isn't parsing or processing any AJAX requests.  The functionality doesn't exist to do so.  If you are using `re`, or otherwise extracting URLs from Javascript, that was never in the code you provided.

Answer (score 2):

use :-

```
try:
    your line to make http requests
except:
    pass
```

with the help of this your crawler will not break .

Comment: I added some code,where should I use try and except?